# Calculate partial derivatives of $exp(-(z^{-4}))$

Tags: complex-analysis

I think I may be being stupid but I can't seem to work how to calculate the partial derivatives of $f(z) = exp(-(z^{-4}))$ at $0$. I understand that they should exist but you then use that this function is not even continuous at $0$ to show that it isn't complex differentiable.

Usually you are given are a function like $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ and you differentiate accordingly to see if $f$ satisfies the Cauchy Riemann equations. But I just can't work out how you'd do this for the function above and I can't seem to find help on the internet.

Thanks

Comment: $f(z)$ isn't even defined at $0$....

Comment: That singularity at $0$ is removable, if you define it as $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad. $f(0) = 0$

Comment: @Kaster: No it isn't....

Comment: @Hyrkyl, 
Isn't
$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \exp \left( -\frac 1{z^4}\right) = 0
$$
?
I'm asking because I'm not sure either. Maybe I'm confusing, and that property is valid for real function only.

Comment: @Kaster: $0$ is an essential singularity of $f$.

Comment: It's not; $z=0$ is an essential singularity. You are correct that if you restrict to real $z$ then the limit does hold. (the same for *purely* imaginary $z$

Comment: @Hurkyl You guys are right. I completely forgot about that.

Comment: What do you mean by "partial derivatives"? It's a function of *one* variable, $z$, so what partial derivatives are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

To show that the function is not continuous at $0$, consider it behavior on a line through the origin on which $-1/z^4$ is positive. (Positive and large exponent $\implies$ humongous exponential function). Writing $z=re^{i\theta}$ may help to identify such a line.

To show that the partial derivative with respect to $x$ exists at $(0,0)$, write $z=x+iy$ and set $y=0$. Observe that $-1/x^4$  is very negative. Therefore, $\exp(-1/x^4)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$. But to show the existence of derivative, we need a little more: 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\exp(-1/x^4)}{x}=0 \tag1$$
Using L'Hospital on (1) directly is undesirable: you'll get a messy derivative. Instead, change the variable to  $u=1/x^4$, turning (1) into a nicer limit
$$\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{\exp(-u)}{1/u^{1/4}}=0 \tag2$$
or, in better form, 
$$\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac{ u^{1/4}}{\exp(u)}=0 \tag3$$
Now L'Hospital works fine.

The consideration of the partial derivative with respect to $y$ is very similar: write $z=x+iy$, set $x=0$, etc.